# How to specify where I want the output to go?

Tags: python, function

I have this script in python which almost works.
Its purpose is to check everyday if files within specific directories were modified today or not
If they were modified today or in the last five days the date and time of them are stored in a text file, if older they aren't stored.

Now I am stuck at the output part. It produces the 3 test files that I asked for the problem is that it doesn't put them in the right places.
I have tried with `os.chdir(input_dir)` and with `glob.glob`. With os.chdir it doesn't put them in the right place and with glob it produces the 3 files but not in the right folder and with the wrong info in them.

Here's my code :

```
    import os, glob, time, datetime


def my_function(output_name, input_dir):
    with open(output_name, "a+") as f:
        os.chdir(input_dir)
        for fichiers in glob.glob("*"):
            today = datetime.datetime.today()
            modified_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fichiers))
            duration = today - modified_date
            if duration.days < 5:
                f.write(f"{fichiers} = {duration} \n")
        

arguments = {"test1.txt" : "//10.2.30.61/c$/Qlikview_Tropal/Apps/Ventes", "test2.txt" : "//10.2.30.61/c$/Qlikview_Tropal/Apps/Marge", "test3.txt" : "//10.2.30.61/c$/Qlikview_Tropal/apps/prod"}
for output_name, input_dir in arguments.items():
    my_function(output_name, input_dir)
```

Edit: So I tried adding f.close(), checking if it is really changing directories and it is but still no progress. What is happening is test1.txt is saved in the folder where my script is ran, test2 in "Ventes" and test3 in "Marge" instead of having test1 in "ventes", 2 in "marge" and 3 in "prod"

EDIT2: Still stuck !! :(

If you have any hints on how to make each test output be in the right folder or in one text file I am all ears

Thank you !

Comment: You should check which directory you are in with os.getcwd() possible that it's not changing to the correct directory when you call os.chdir(input_dir)

Comment: I have checked with getcwd it does change folders as expected  `PS C:\Users\mmi\Desktop\code\python\.vscode> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python38-32/python.exe" c:/Users/mmi/Desktop/code/python/.vscode/test.py
\\10.2.30.61\c$\Qlikview_Tropal\Apps\Ventes
\\10.2.30.61\c$\Qlikview_Tropal\Apps\Marge
\\10.2.30.61\c$\Qlikview_Tropal\apps\prod
PS C:\Users\mmi\Desktop\code\python\.vscode>`

Comment: Then it might have something to do with you not closing the file with f.close()?

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `os.path.join(...)`:

```
def my_function(output_name, input_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    with open(file_path, "a+") as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Okay this gives me the same result as with glob.glob. The issue is instead of having the modified dates and times of the files in "//10.2.30.61/c$/Qlikview_Tropal/Apps/Ventes" for exemple, it has the date and time of the files it just created instead like so                 "test.py = 0:00:01.386192 
test1.txt = 0:00:00.001000 
test2.txt = 0:00:00 
test3.txt = 0:00:00"